# How to disable incognito mode in Ferrum?

Tags: ruby

How can I turn off incognito mode when I start Chrome with Ferrum?

This is my code, I was trying to use user-data-dir, but it didn`t help me

```
require "ferrum"

BROWSER_PATH="C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"

# run bot
def akira
    chrome = Ferrum::Browser.new(
        browser_path:BROWSER_PATH,
        headless:false,
        browser_options:{
            'no-sandbox':nil,
            '--incognito':false,
            'user-data-dir':'E:/ruby/akira/session',
        }
    )
    chrome.go_to("https://google.com")
    chrome.screenshot(path: "google.png")
    chrome.quit
end

akira
```

Comment: I would expect it to be `'incognito': false` to match the format of the other options.

Comment: @Ry- not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome = Ferrum::Browser.new(
    browser_path:BROWSER_PATH,
    headless:false,
    browser_options:{
        'no-sandbox':nil,
        'incognito':nil
    }    
    user_data_dir: 'E:/ruby/akira/session'
)
```

Comment: This actually turns on incognito mode.